# Using inspect.getargfullspec() to find out about functions not working

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to learn what options and parameters a function has so I can use it to the fullest. For example, I want to learn what sort of arguments the default `print()` function accepts, and perhaps some documentation on the parameters e.g. what each argument does, the options for each argument and so on. I've read around and saw that `getargfullspec()` is the method. Am I right, or is there an easier way to do this?

Anyhow, I tried it but got an error.

```
import inspect
inspect.getfullargspec(print)
```

It gave this error.

```
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Not possible with functions written in C, at least not easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only functions that `inspect.getfullargspec` supports are those created in Python code with `def` or `lambda`.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec):

> `inspect.getfullargspec(func)`
>
> Get the names and default values of a **Python** function's arguments.

Emphasis mine.  `print` however is not technically a *Python* function because it is written in C:

```
>>> import types
>>> # FunctionType represents Python functions
>>> isinstance(print, types.FunctionType)
False
>>> # BuiltinFunctionType represents C functions
>>> isinstance(print, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
>>>
```

That is why a `TypeError` is raised for passing it to `inspect.getfullargspec`.

---

Also, using `inspect.getfullargspec` to get information about a function is only really used in metaprogramming.  If you are simply looking for documentation or usage, you should use [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) in the interactive interpreter as @thomas said or read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) online.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this on a function with the following code:help(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfiles) 
and got this
askopenfiles(mode='r', **options)
    Ask for multiple filenames and return the open file
    objects

How do I find out in more detail, what parameters **options take?

Comment: The `**` means that the function takes any number of keyword arguments.  For a list of what you can pass to `askopenfiles`, see the documentation: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find about a function, is to read its docstring and see how it was implemented. This can be done by running the help() function

I.E - `help(int)` shows you what can be done with the `int()` function

```
class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> int or long
 |  int(x, base=10) -> int or long
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.
 |  If x is outside the integer range, the function returns a long instead.
 |  
 |  If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
 |  Unicode object representing an integer literal in the given base.  The
 |  literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded by whitespace.
 |  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.  Base 0 means to
 |  interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
 |  >>> int('0b100', base=0)
 |  4
```

Or for example -

```
import datetime
help(datetime.datetime.strptime)
```

will return

```
strptime(...)
    string, format -> new datetime parsed from a string (like time.strptime()).
```

You can read more about the `help()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help)